# ansible: how to use a interactive python script (custom module)

Tags: python, ansible

please advise the way to use python interactive script as custom module.

my python script sometimes prompts like below.

```
[ansible@localhost ~]$ python test.py
No errors found.
do you want to proceed [y/n]
[ansible@localhost ~]$
```

`sometimes:`

```
[ansible@localhost ~]$ python test.py
3 Errors found.
Cant proceed with script.
[ansible@localhost ~]$
```

output result & interactive output may vary depending on the conditions, written in my script.

i want to understand how to use this script under custom module in ansible, and deal with interactive prompt responses..

i read that `expect` module can help in ansible, to provide response, but in my script, response cant be same all the time.

for example, i have tried expect module to and it failed since my python script result was different, it has 4-6various responses as per conditions.

```
"invocation": {
    "module_args": {
        "chdir": null,
        "command": "/usr/bin/python3 test3.py",
        "creates": null,
        "echo": true,
        "removes": null,
        "responses": {
            "do you want to proceed [y/n]": "y"
        },
        "timeout": 30
```

above failed output is when ansible expect a response as mentioned above, but my actual python script result was different.

please advice.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood the problem, your script gives you multiple possibilities. This is how I will handle it using pexpect module in a yml file for with ansible-playbook:

```
---

- hosts      : localhost
  remote_user: USER_NAME
  tasks      :
    - name  : run the script
      expect:
        echo     : yes
        command  : /usr/bin/python3 test3.py
        timeout  : 30
        responses:
          (?i)do you want to proceed [y/n]                                       : "y"
          (?i)2nd OPTION                                                         : "y/n"
          (?i)3rd OPTION                                                         : "y/n"
```